# Network of flows

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a [digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph). We call it "cyclable" if there exists $k$ $\geq$ 1 circuits in $G$,$C_1$,...$C_k$, of which sets of vertices, V($C_1$),...,V($C_k$) , makes a partition of $V(G)$.

I must prove that:

We can test  in polynomial time (in terms of $|V| + |E|$ )  whether a digraph $G=(V,E)$ is cyclable, solving a problem of maximum flow value in a network of flows convenient built.

The property of "cyclable" is easy to understand, but I have problems on the second part of the problem.

We must test that property using a maximum flow problem.

I tried to construct a network, and find a flow and check every vertex to see what flows it gives. Is this a good idea to start? And how do i continue?

Comment: Post it to cs.se. It is more likely to get helpful answers there.